# Is it a concern if the pending transaction date is wrong on credit card?

Tags: credit-card, canada

I have 8 pending transactions on my credit card. Yesterday I went to a store and bought something with it. But the transaction shows up with today's date instead of yesterdays. Today I bought something from another store and it shows up with today's date. Is this some kind of problem or anything I should be concerned about?

What exactly is "pending"? They obviously have all the information (because I can read the date, amount, store etc) so why have this additional stage before it's just part of the balance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not a problem if the transaction date shown on your credit card company’s website is off by a day. It happens, and it is nothing to be concerned about.

For the second question in your post, the reason for the “pending” waiting period, this has been discussed in this question:

[Why do credit card transactions take up to 3 days to appear, yet debit transactions are instant?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/37606/10997)

Comment: As an aside, you use the word "bank" but I do no banking with the institution that provides my credit card. I mean, would it be correct to call American Express (for example) a bank because you can't deposit or withdraw money from them etc. I guess I'm asking, is it correct to call the institution where you get you're credit card from a bank?

Comment: For example Walmart has there own credit card, but you wouldn't call Walmart a bank.

Comment: Credit cards are issued by banks. The Walmart credit card is issued by Capital One. American Express is a bank. But to be less confusing, I have edited my answer.